# Ruby on Rails - Passing parameters to set in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, parameters, routes

this maybe is an usual and easy ask to answer but Im new in this.
I have my route and view asociated to my webtool ready and working, the route is like this "mysite.com/calculator". Its about some charts which change their values depends of choices in some levers (1 up to 4). I need to add the functionality to navigate at some url like "mysite.com/calculator/1113231" where the numbers are the choices preselected.
If i can do some like that I'll need to get the numbers and set the levers by JS i think.
Some advise and/or example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# everything in parenthesis after the path 
# helper is added as a hash to the URL
# parameters
calculator_path(number1: 80085, number2: 58008)
```

...will translate to

```
# parameters added to a URL is noted
# by the '?' followed by each parameter
# assigned and it's value
/calculator?number1=80085&number2=58008
```

Then you can pull the params down in your controller

```
first_number  = params[:number1]
second_number = params[:number2]
```

If you want to add a dynamic value, use a variable that gets assignment from somewhere else in your code....

```
calculator_path(x: @rdm_num_1, y: @rnd_num_2)
```

Comment: What if i the number is random?, i mean, each digit represent a choice between 1 and 4, the cuantity of them is equal to the number of levers in my web. And how is the declaration in routes.rb?

Comment: The number can be whatever you want it to be. Assign it with an instance variable or random integer. The main point above is how you pass parameters into a URL. everything in parenthesis after the path is a hash that is added to the URL parameters. Useful for redirects and passing information from a view to controller via links or buttons.

Comment: You don't have to modify your routes to accomplish this.